# Printing the smallest number inputed (Excluding any negatives)

Tags: c++, min

The program I am writing lets the user input as many positive integers as they want. However, it is supposed to exit when someone inputs a negative number.

So far I have all of this working well for me. My next issue is printing the smallest positive number.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip> 

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int input; 
    int count; 
    int min; 

    count = 0;

    cout << "Input a positive integer to begin: ";
    cin >> input; 
    count++; 

    while(input > 0)
    {
        cout << "Continue to input positive integers. Enter negative number to exit: ";
        cin >> input; 
        count++;
        min = input; 

        if (input < min);
        min = input; 

        if (input < 0)
        {
            cout << "\nLowest number: " << min << endl; 
            cout << "Total numbers inputed: " << --count << endl;
            break; 
        }
    }
}
```

So far the code is giving me this when I run it:

Input a positive integer to begin: 45

Continue to input positive integers. Enter negative number to exit: 48

Continue to input positive integers. Enter negative number to exit: 74

Continue to input positive integers. Enter negative number to exit: 1

Continue to input positive integers. Enter negative number to exit: -1

Lowest number: -1

Total numbers inputed: 4

However I would want it to print out that the Lowest Number is 1 or whatever small POSITIVE integer that the user inputs.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have 2 problem that cause this:

1:

```
if (input < min);
```

you shouldn't put semi colon after `if`, whether it be true or false the code that immediately comes after `if` will execute

2: after fixing first problem:

```
 if (input < min)
        min = input;
```

it will assign any `input` to `min` that have the condition, even negative number
so you must add another condition to be sure that the `input` is positive and then assign it

```
 if ((input < min) && (input > 0))
          min = input;
```

EDIT: you need to remove `min = input;`that placed exactly before `if`

the complete code:

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <iomanip.h>



int main()
{
     int input;
     int count;
     int min;

     count = 0;

     cout << "Input a positive integer to begin: ";
     cin >> input;
     count++;

     while(input > 0)
     {
          cout << "Continue to input positive integers. Enter negative number to exit: ";
          cin >> input;
          count++;


          if ((input < min) && (input > 0))
             min = input;

          if (input < 0)
          {
                cout << "\nLowest number: " << min << endl;
                cout << "Total numbers inputed: " << --count << endl;
                break;
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it still said that my lowest number is the negative :/

Comment: @Jane : oh yes, sorry, i forgot to remove something, i will edit

Comment: Hi there. I have also tried that and still no success. I need to have min = input; somewhere before the if statement or else it won't know what variable to compare the input to

Comment: @Jane i will add the complete code that works for me in my post

Comment: Here is a more updated version of what I have for me at the moment http://pastebin.com/zcPHbB6R

Comment: @Jane your updated cod was also o0key for me and show me the lowest number

Comment: Your updated code still didn't work for me. It just went back to assigning the lowest number to 0 sadly.

Comment: @Jane after your first `cin` add `min=input;` . and instead of using `if(count>=1)` use `if(count>=1 && input<min)`

Answer (score 0):

You update your least number before you check if it's negative:

```c
if (input < min)
    ...
if (input < 0)
    ...
```

All you need to do is swap the two if-blocks so that when a negative number is encountered the program checked it for negativeness first, and `break` was executed before the second if-block.

Also, there seems to be an extra semicolon in your code (and an extra assignment?)

Comment: I tried this but since the program now breaks once the negative is entered it never assigns the lowest variable so now it says "Lowest number = 0"

Comment: @Jane You never initialize `min` to anything, and it contains a random value (like 0). Consider a statement like `if(count == 1) min = input`, which means that in an array of one element, the element is the minimum.

Comment: I tried this as well. It now only prints out the last positive integer I input. For some odd reasons I just can't get it to spit out the lowest number

Comment: @Jane Could you please paste your current code somewhere (like a pastebin)?

Comment: @Jane `==` not `>=`. Also where did the other if block go (`if (input < min)`)? Actually disregard that, you input the first number separately, just add `min = input` after you input the very first number (line 15).

Comment: I changed the '==' to '>=' because my count will go up the more numbers the user keeps inputting. an I removed the other if statement because it wasn't doing anything to fix the problem either